# Accessing Entity Passed to Form Builder with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony4, symfony-forms

I am building a form using the Symfony framework and am trying to understand how to pass an instance of an entity to the form builder.

Controller:

```
$organization = $user->getOrganization();
$form = $this->createForm(OrganizationCourseType::class, $organization);
```

OrganizationCourseType class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('courses', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Course::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('course')
                    ->andWhere('course.organization = :organization')
                    ->setParameter('organization', $organization);
            },
        ]);
    }
```

However I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: organization
```

How can I access the entity (organization) within the form builder? Do I need to pass it as an option? If so what is the point of including it in the createForm call in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, pass the instance of your entity as a third argument to your `$form` definition line:

```
$form = $this->createForm(OrganizationCourseType::class, null, ['organization' => $organization]);
```

Then retrieve it in your FormType class like so:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $organization = $options['organization'];

    $builder->add('courses', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Course::class,
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('course')
                ->andWhere('course.organization = :organization')
                ->setParameter('organization', $organization);
        },
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(['organization']);
}
```

Comment: With your exact example I am still getting a undefined organization error. However, working off you example if I change line 3 to $this->organization = $options['organization']; and the setParameter reference to $this->organization it works. Thanks!

Comment: @user1392897: Hmmm, I can't explain that one. Glad it works, but the code I wrote should work as well.

Comment: Found the issue... I had to add 'use' like so: 'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($organization) {

Answer (score 2):

To address the second part of your question: "what is the point of including it in the `createForm` call ?"

When you pass an object as the second argument to `createFormBuilder` you are passing the initial data for the form. Symfony will try to find properties (or getters/setters) that match the form field name in the object and assign its value to the field. Then, on submission, it'll update your model accordingly.

You'd tipically pass the same type of object as the form's `data_class`, so in your case that would be an `OrganizationCourse`. You could do something like the following:

```
$organizationCourse = new OrganizationCourse();
$organizationCourse->setOrganization($user->getOrganization());
$form = $this->createForm(OrganizationCourseType::class, $organizationCourse);
```

You could select many `Courses` and assign them to the `Organization`.
However, this doesn't look like your use case, since `OrganizationCourse` looks like a relation rather than an entity, so refer to [@ehimel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957626#56958090).